# How to calculate per day salary into minutes in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got per day salary but that per day salary i need to calculate/convert into minutes. Suppose my per day salary is 1166.67 so i need calculate/convert in minutes. Please provide formula those i use in excel sheet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just divide it by 1440 , will give u salary per minute.

Comment: Or if you consider 8 hours of work a day, then divide it by 480

Comment: So you're basically asking how many minutes per day you are working?

Comment: If you're daily salary is $1,166.67 then you should hire someone to do these kinds of calculations for you.  I'm available.

Comment: @ashleedawg it's probably rupees... sadly :)

Comment: @SolarMike oh yeah, I guess the whole world isn't paid in Canadian dollars, eh?

Comment: Better than the Yen

Answer (score 2):

### Pay per minute of day

If the `Pay per Day` was in cell `A2` and you wanted to calculate the **`Pay per Minute`-*`of the Day`***, you could use the formula:

### `=A2/(24*60)`

[image: img]

---

### Pay per minute of shift

If you actually wanted to know the **`Pay per Minute`-*`of the Hours Worked`***, then you are missing a key piece of information: ***"How many hours is a shift?"***.

If you have the `Pay per Day` was in cell `A2` and the `Hours Worked` was in cell `B2`, you could use formula:

### `=A2/(24*60)`

[image: img]

---

> You can download the above examples as a **sample file** from [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43591575995775972745).